# Any chance a crontab entry is deleted automatically after the entry is commented?

Tags: cron

Maybe I'm mistaken, but it seems that every-time I commented out a crontab entry,
it will deleted automatically.

eg.

```
ssh server
crontab -e
```

commented out an entry using "#", save and quit

Next day

```
crontab -e
```

// notice the previously commented entry is disappear

User is root, using vi as editor, running on CentOS 5.7,
and the version of crontab (from man crontab) is Cron V4.1

Comment: Other ones you did not commented out are still there?

Comment: Yes, that's the part I dun understand

Answer (score 0):

Try marking your comments with `#` rather than using the `//`, if I'm reading what you're doing correctly.

Comment: sorry, I'm using #

Comment: Ah, my bad, I read it wrong then.  Are you logging in as root via ssh?   Are you sure you're looking at the same user's crontab each time?

Comment: Yup, login as root.And only root has existing crontab.